# require.js module.config() in node.js?

Tags: node.js, requirejs

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig

illustrates a way which you can pass arguments to your requirejs modules.

It works in a browser environment but in node.js module.config() is empty.

Is module.config() supposed to work in node.js or am I trying impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

testfile.js

```
define(['module'], function(module){
  console.log(module.config().foo)
})
```

index.js - located in the same folder as testfile.js

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs')

requirejs.config({
  config: {
    'testfile': {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
});

requirejs(['testfile'], function(){
  // 'bar' is printed in the console
})
```

Comment: Thanks. well i'm using requirejs in node.js as described in http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html